# Should I edit old questions to add newly created tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, old-questions

I am active in [repository-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository-pattern) tag. While answering (and asking) about it, I noticed the need of [generic-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generic-repository) sub tag. While answering one of the question, I edited the question to create this tag.

I have already answered some questions from [repository-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository-pattern) tag earlier. Some of which also qualify newly created [generic-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generic-repository) sub tag.

Should I edit old questions to add newly created tag?

Comment: Both suggestions are missing an article in the first sentence. "Generic Repository is **a** generic ...".

Comment: @BDL: I tried but could not find good article from good source (Microsoft/Wikipedia etc.) that **define** generic repository in language-agnostic and ORM-agnostic way. Please suggest if any.

Comment: I would disagree that there is a need for a `generic-repository` tag. A generic repository is just the repository pattern paired with generics to allow code reuse. There is nothing special about it that makes it deserve its own tag.

Comment: @poke: I agree but I am not sure. I have asked different [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372419/5779732).