# Is [generic-repository] a valid/on-topic tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

I recently created [generic-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generic-repository) tag.

In [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), I read following:

> **When should I create new tags?**
>   Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that **your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before** on this site.

No, the tag does not cover **new topic** on this site. Other tag [repository-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository-pattern) cover everything that can be covered under new tag that I created.

But, I still think new tag is on-topic and valid on this site. It is actually sub tag of existing one. We have many language/tool tags and sub tags with their versions. We have [orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orm) and also have tags with specific ORMs.

I am not involved on tag related activities on meta and on main site too much. I may not explain my reasoning in good sense. That is why I put this for community to discuss.

I have asked different [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372416/5779732) related to this tag. **I will wait until community agree/disagree on that**.

Comment: 42 Views, +3/-2 votes on question and +6 votes on answer from @poke. I do not think the decision matters much to community. I will leave this as is. I will NOT re-tag the old questions. I will NOT remove the tag from existing 1 question. Future users may use this tag.

Answer (score 8):

As per [my comment on the other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372416/should-i-edit-old-questions-to-add-newly-created-tag?noredirect=1#comment620317_372416), I do not believe that this is a good fit for a tag. A generic repository is still a repository, and as such it’s a way to apply the [repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). It’s just that it uses generics to enable code reuse for a few basic and unspecific operations.

So every question that is about a generic repository, is also a question about the repository pattern. So any question tagged with [generic-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generic-repository) would have to be tagged with [repository-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository-pattern).

In general, there would be nothing wrong with that, we do have some tag pairs like that. However, I do not think that the [generic-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generic-repository) tag is useful anyway:

If you look at resources about a generic repository, what you find most are recommendations *not* to use it. It is often considered an anti-pattern. So I would expect questions that really are about a generic repository to always have some answer that goes in the direction of recommending *against* using a generic repository, moving to a non-generic repository (or even skipping it completely).

There are only a handful of different question variations I could think of until we can probably close all the remaining ones as duplicates of another. So I don’t believe there’s any gain with such a tag.

Comment: Even though pair-tagged, we can classify the question question for generic repository easily. This will be advantage. About your second last paragraph, what we put in answer should not be the criteria for existence/non-existence of the tag IMHO.

Comment: @AmitJoshi I understood that more like "what's the point of adding a tag if it refers to something that people should always avoid", not like "we should base the tags on the answer's content".